# How to port an existing number to Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice, phone-number

This [post on the Google Voice forums, dated in April of 2010,](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=425cdabe3aafc385&hl=en) says that GV has **not** added support for porting existing numbers (such as a landline) to GV.

*Is this still true?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the [suggestion page](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs) still lists **Port a number to Google Voice** as one of the options, that post is still valid. Google will remove it from the feature request page once they implement it. If you would like to increase the chances of this happening, submit a request for that feature.

[This answer](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115102) is also under Google's control and will probably be updated once the feature is implemented.

Answer (score 4):

It is now possible to [port an existing mobile number to Google Voice](http://googlevoiceblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/port-your-existing-mobile-number-to.html), for a fee.  Note that this is not yet available for land line numbers or corporate mobile numbers.